# Nmap too slow with a network that can't access to internet

Tags: networking, nmap

I am using CentOS 6.5 and Nmap 5.51

I want to find all alive IPs in a LAN between two IPs

Easily get the answer

```
sudo nmap -sP 192.168.1.100-200
```

my problem when my network can access to internet the total time spend is **1.78 seconds** but when my network can't access to internet the total time spend is **17.79 seconds**

**output with internet**

```
[mgmt_user@Management root]$ sudo nmap -sP 192.168.1.100-200

Starting Nmap 5.51 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2014-05-21 23:05 EEST
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.106
Host is up (0.00054s latency).
MAC Address: 08:00:27:93:2E:C5 (Cadmus Computer Systems)
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.126
Host is up (0.0013s latency).
MAC Address: 00:16:3E:63:64:A0 (Xensource)
Nmap done: 101 IP addresses (2 hosts up) scanned in 1.78 seconds
```

**output without internet**

```
[mgmt_user@Management root]$ sudo nmap -sP 192.168.1.100-200

Starting Nmap 5.51 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2014-05-21 23:02 EEST
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.106
Host is up (0.00042s latency).
MAC Address: 08:00:27:93:2E:C5 (Cadmus Computer Systems)
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.126
Host is up (0.0011s latency).
MAC Address: 00:16:3E:63:64:A0 (Xensource)
Nmap done: 101 IP addresses (2 hosts up) scanned in 17.79 seconds
```

repeat the command many time and have the same time

is there any link between Nmap and the internet ?

Comment: Can you please paste complete output of nmap command when your network does not have access to Internet?

Comment: please check question update

Comment: try `-n` to disable DNS resolution.

Comment: try also --max-rtt-timeout 100ms, and  --max-retries 0 to prevent any retransmissions

Comment: @derobert thank you solved with `-n` please answer the question

Comment: OK, I'll post an answer once I'm home.

Comment: @vladeli  when I used `--max-retries 0` time=0.68 and throw Warnings `Warning: 192.168.1.147 giving up on port because retransmission cap hit (0).`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `nmap` is trying to [query](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_DNS_lookup) DNS servers to resolve the hostnames associated with the IP addresses your scanning.

Because it cannot succeed to do so, it times out, but you get the extra delay in the meanwhile.

**Use the `-n` option with `nmap` to avoid this.** That would be:

```
sudo nmap -n -sP 192.168.1.100-200
```

If you had a properly configured local DNS server however, it would probably have answered quickly (usually saying that no hostname corresponds) and you wouldn't have noticed this problem in the first place.